# Spring Boot cloud config does not handle Google Secret Manager tokens

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, gcp-secret-manager

I am running a web app using Spring Boot 2.6.10 with external configuration.  Our configuration server is secure, so credentials must be provided.  The credentials are stored in Google Cloud Secret Manager.  However, it seems that the Spring Cloud Config section of the application.yml does not recognize the secret manager notation (**sm://**).  Properties outside of the spring cloud config section resolve the secret manager tokens correctly.  As a sanity check, I entered the plain text credentials in the application.yml and the properties loaded just fine.  Am I missing a dependency or an updated version of Spring Boot or Spring Boot Cloud?

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>smtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Secret Manager Test</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.3.0</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.10</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.yml

```yaml
io:
  my:
    data:
      # These tokens resolve
      user: "${sm://my-gcp-project/my-data-user/latest}"
      password: "${sm://my-gcp-project/my-data-password/latest}"
spring:
  application:
    name: smtest
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://my-external-config.io
      # These tokens DO NOT resolve
      username: "${sm://my-gcp-project/ext-config-user/latest}"
      password: "${sm://my-gcp-project/ext-config-password/latest}"
  config:
    import: "configserver:"
```

Comment: Looks like [my issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76064326/gcp-secret-manager-environment-variables-and-secrets-not-resolved-in-spring-boo) - have you been able to solve this?

Comment: @StefanFalk yes, i believe so.  It seems using the following versions works for me now:
Spring Boot - 2.7.10
Spring Cloud - 2021.0.5
Spring Cloud GCP - 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue is resolved by Spring Boot.  Using more recent versions of Spring Boot and cloud dependencies resolved this.

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).